# How to pass NULLs in array to Postgres stored procedure using pg8000?

Tags: python, arrays, postgresql, stored-procedures, pg8000

In Python 3.8 I'm using pg8000 1.21.3 to call a Postgress 11 stored procedure which takes as an argument a custom data type array. Here is the working proof of concept schema and stored procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myproc;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
DROP TYPE mytype;

CREATE TYPE mytype AS (
    an_int     INT,
    a_bool     BOOL,
    a_decimal  DECIMAL,
    a_string   TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE mytable(
    id         SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    an_int     INT,
    a_bool     BOOL,
    a_decimal  DECIMAL,
    a_string   TEXT
);

CREATE PROCEDURE myproc(
    IN myarray mytype[]
)
AS $$
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO mytable(
            an_int,
            a_bool,
            a_decimal,
            a_string
        ) SELECT
            an_int,
            a_bool,
            a_decimal,
            a_string
        FROM
            unnest(myarray);
    END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CALL myproc(
    array[
            (1, 1, 2.1, 'foo'),
            (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
        ]::mytype[]
);

SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

The output of the select is:

```
 id | an_int | a_bool | a_decimal | a_string 
----+--------+--------+-----------+----------
  1 |      1 | t      |       2.1 | foo
  2 |        |        |           | 
(2 rows)
```

meaning that when I invoke the stored procedure from SQL, I can create a row with all null values.

I am now trying to achieve the same from Python using pg8000.
To pass an array with some null values, the only way it seems to work is to replace `None` with an empty string. This works for integers and text data types, but it fails for booleans and decimals:

```
import pg8000

arr = [(1, True, 3.2, 'foo'),
       (None, True, 3.2, 'foo'),
       (1, True, 3.2, None),
       (1, False, 3.2, 'foo'),
       (1, None, 3.2, 'foo'),  # <---- boolean null fails
        (1, False, None, 'foo'), # <---- decimal null fails
       ]

sql = """CALL myproc(%s::mytype[]);"""
stm = [str(item) for item in arr]
stm = [item.replace('None', '') for item in stm]

with pg8000.connect(host="localhost", database="mydb", user="myuser", password="mypass") as con:
    with con.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            sql,
            args=(stm,)
        )
    con.commit()
```

and the error is:

`pg8000.dbapi.ProgrammingError: {'S': 'ERROR', 'V': 'ERROR', 'C': '22P02', 'M': 'invalid input syntax for type boolean: " "', 'F': 'bool.c', 'L': '154', 'R': 'boolin'}`

How can I pass nulls for all these data types using pg8000 parameter interpolation, that is without hardcoding the sql statement?

Answer (score 0):

With version 1.29.6 of pg8000 you should be able to do:

```
import pg8000

arr = [
    (1, True, 3.2, "foo"),
    (None, True, 3.2, "foo"),
    (1, True, 3.2, None),
    (1, False, 3.2, "foo"),
    (1, None, 3.2, "foo"),  # <---- boolean null fails
    (1, False, None, "foo"),  # <---- decimal null fails
]

sql = """CALL myproc(%s::mytype[]);"""

with pg8000.connect(database="typetest", user="postgres", password="pg") as con:
    with con.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(sql, args=(arr,))
    con.commit()
```

since pg8000 now interprets a `tuple` as a composite type.